# Верно ли расставлены знаки пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация

"Но следующий - поверь мне, намного лучший."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Неверно.

"Поверь мне" - вводное, обособляется запятыми.

"Намного лучший" - ошибка в образовании сравнительной степени. "Лучший" - это уже превосходная степень.

Точка всегда ставится за закрывающими кавычками.

***Но следующий, поверь мне, намного лучше.***